# Executing my own groovy script in php

Tags: php, drupal, groovy

Hi I have this groovy script (in $FRAPID_HOME/bin) and I want to call it in Drupal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy 

def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'frapid-generate-keys projectPath')
def opt = cli.parse(args)

if ( opt.h || opt.arguments().isEmpty() ) {
   cli.usage()
   return
}

def path = "."

println("Generating keys...")
def frapid = new Frapid()
println '---->' + opt.arguments()[0]
println("Keys genarated")
~
```

the php code is this:

```
function api_manager_generate_keys_form_submit( $form, &$form_state) {

   $output = shell_exec( 'frapid-generate-keys '. $form_state['values']['api_manager_project_root'] );

   drupal_set_message( $output );

}
```

my .bashrc configuration is this:

```
export FRAPID_HOME=/home/admin1/frapid
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
export GROOVY_HOME=/home/admin1/groovy-2.0.1

export CLASSPATH=$FRAPID_HOME/classes:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

when I tried to execute in drupal apache gives me this error:

```
sh: 1: frapi-generate-keys: not found
```

then I tried  giving the absolute path:

```
$output = shell_exec( '/home/admin1/frapid/bin/frapid-generate-keys '. $form_state['values']['api_manager_project_root'] );
```

but is still in error:

```
/usr/bin/env: groovy: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the script manually, from command line?

Comment: from command line it works well

Comment: Does the webserver user have permission to access that folder?

Comment: Yes:
drwxrwxr-x  8 admin1 admin1    4096 Aug 27 05:23 frapid/
drwxrwxr-x  2 admin1 admin1 4096 Aug 30 16:16 bin/

Comment: I called this getenv("PATH"); in drupal and I have this /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin ---------

But in shell is /home/admin1/frapid/bin:/home/admin1/groovy-2.0.1/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: that user has a different path ...how can I change it?

Comment: You could add it to the Drupal's `PATH` environment variable, no? It would not look good, but for a urgent solution i think it would work

Comment: I think the drupal's user doesn't have a path to Groovy's home neither Java's home. Editing your own `.bashrc` won't solve that. I  think you need to work on the path for that user. Maybe extending the environment variables to Drupal's user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Apache has a different file configuration for the PATH variable.
For ubuntu the file is /etc/apache2/envvars, here we can 'export' our variables